# AS3 reference buttons

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

How can I make this work? I need to remove the word Button from the reference to reference the actual item that will be tinted. Thank you in advance.

```
disagreeButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, mouseRollOver);
contentMain.clickButton1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, mouseRollOver);

function mouseRollOver(e:MouseEvent):void { 
    var c:Color = new Color();
    c.setTint (0xFFFFFF, 1);
    //the issue is this line:
    this[e.target.name.replace( "Button", "" )].transform.colorTransform = c;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with this solution? Does it compile? Run? Have unexpected side effects?

Comment: TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
 at index_test_fla::MainTimeline/mouseRollOver()

only get this error for "contentMain.clickButton1"

Comment: Have you tested that `e.target.name.replace("Button","")` evaluates to what you think it does?

Comment: Well `e.target.name.replace("Button","")` is a string so it will not work.

Comment: The problem is that `e.target.name.replace("Button","")` does not contain the name of the movieclip is in, which is contentMain.

Comment: Yes, but **what is that string**? Your error means that `this[...]` doesn't exist. Are you sure that the `target` is what you think it is? Are you sure that the names of both items match?

Comment: ...have you tried contentMain[...] instead of this[...]?

Comment: Oh I am sorry I misread your comment. `e.target.name.replace("Button","")` works perfectly with `disagreeButton` but with the `contentMain.clickButton1` it does not. It only returns `clickButton1` when I do a trace. It is missing the path.

Comment: I can not use `contentMain[...]` because the first item is not located in `contentMain`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I understand your problem, I would recommend the following.

1. Have separate methods for buttons in `this`, and in `contentMain`, and any others. Then access the objects by `this[...]` or `contentMain[...]`, where appropriate.

   ```
   disagreeButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, mainMouseRollOver);
   contentMain.clickButton1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, contentMainMouseRollOver);

   function mainMouseRollOver(e:MouseEvent):void { 
       mouseRolloverLogic(this[e.target.name.replace( "Button", "" )];
   }

   function contentMainMouseRollOver(e:MouseEvent):void { 
       mouseRolloverLogic(contentMain[e.target.name.replace( "Button", "" )];
   }

   function mouseRolloverLogic(item:DisplayObject):void {
       var c:Color = new Color();
       c.setTint (0xFFFFFF, 1);
       item.transform.colorTransform = c;
   }
   ```
2. Add extra logic to the method you have.

   ```
   if (this[...] != null) {
       ...
   }else if (contentMain[...] != null) {
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you this works. Is there a "cleaner" way to do this or no?

Comment: @Anderson The first option would probably be considered 'cleaner'. Just make different `mouseRollOver` functions for Buttons in `contentMain` and Buttons in the main app.

Comment: Seems weird to repeat a function only because of the target difference. I just thought there would be a more efficient way to have all the code on the main timeline.

Comment: Could make the multiple `mouseRollOver` functions grab whatever object they are supposed to work on, and then pass it to an internal function. They act like a wrapper to the actual functionality. Less code duplication.

Comment: To just make sure I am on the same page, you are saying to make a separate function that contains the tint and `mouseRollOver` just calls that function from where it is?

Comment: Sounds like you understand. I'll edit up my answer to show how I'm thinking of it.